# Normal curvature along a line of curvature

Tags: differential-geometry

I have come across the following exercise (the context is curves and surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and the Gauss map):

> If $C=\alpha(I)$ is a line of curvature, and $k$ is its curvature at $p$, then
>   $$ k = \mid k_n k_N \mid $$
>   where $k_n$ is the normal curvature at $p$ along the tagent line of $C$, and $k_N$ is the curvature of the spherical image $N(C) \subset S^2$ at $N(p)$.

I am not sure I understand the question, though... because it seems to me that if $C$ is a line of curvature, the normal curvature should be identical to the curvature of $C$ itself, hence  $k = k_n$. Am I mistaken?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$C$ being a line of curvature means that the tangent vector of $C$ at every point is a principal direction, not that its normal curvature is identical to its curvature.

To solve your problem, you will need a formula for curvature that doesn't use parameterization by arc-length since the gauss map doesn't always give a curve parameterized by arc length. Let's use

$k(t) = \frac{|\alpha' \times \alpha''|}{|\alpha'|^3}$ (exercise 12 in section 1-5 of Do Carmo, which you are probably using?)

$C$ being a line of curvature means that the Gauss map $N$ is such that

$N'(t) = \lambda(t) \alpha'(t)$ where $-\lambda(t)$ is the curvature in the direction of $\alpha'(t)$

If you compute the curvature $k_N$ using these two formulas you should get the result after rearranging. Comment if you have more questions :)

Comment: Thanks, that helped me to solve the exercise! Though I am still having a hard time visualizing this curve...

Comment: I tried to find a way to "see" the result too but was unsuccessful so far...

Comment: @Vhailor my computations yield $k=k_N |\lambda(t)|$

Comment: I only get $k=k_n k_2 /k_1$...

Comment: @Vhailor  Thank you.  I can sleep at night again.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

Let $\beta=N\circ\alpha$. Without loss of generality, let's say that $\beta^{\prime}(t)=dN_{p}(\alpha^{\prime}(t))=-k_{1}\alpha^{\prime}(t)$, then $\beta^{\prime\prime}(t)=-k_{1}\alpha^{\prime\prime}(t)$. Since we don't know if $\beta$ is parameterized by arc length, we will use the formula for curvature.

\begin{eqnarray*}
\left|k_{n}K_{N}\right| & = & \left|k_{1}\right|\frac{\left|\beta^{\prime}\land\beta^{\prime\prime}\right|}{\left|\beta^{\prime}\right|^{3}}\
& = & \left|k_{1}\right|\frac{\left|k_{1}\alpha^{\prime}\land k_{1}\alpha^{\prime\prime}\right|}{\left|k_{1}\alpha^{\prime}\right|^{3}}\
& = & \left|k_{1}\right|\frac{\left|k_{1}k_{1}k\right|}{\left|k_{1}\right|^{3}}\
& = & k.
\end{eqnarray*}